# Taylor series of $\sin (z)$ at $z_0 = a$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Hey I'm new to complex Analysis and need help with this task. Need to find the series of $\sin (z)$ at $z_0 =a$ where $a$ is complex.

I have started the task using the definition of series: $$f(z) = \sum_ {n= 0}^{\infty}  a_n (z- z_0)^n$$ where $a_n$ ist the n-th differential of $\frac{\sin (z_0)}{n!}$

Please help

Comment: You can use `z_0` instead of `z0`, and `\sin (z)` instead of `sin(z)`, to make it look better.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

First, change variable $z=x+a$. So,

$$\sin(z)=\sin(x+a)=\sin(a)\cos(x)+\cos(a)\sin(x)$$ and use the expansions of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ around $x=0$.

Comment: and what about sin(a), cos(a) ? may I use also the expansions around 0? I mean just typing a instead of x?

Comment: @MateD. They are constants. However, since $a=\alpha+i\beta$ you probably need to use $\sin(a)=\sin (\alpha ) \cosh (\beta )+i \cos (\alpha ) \sinh (\beta )$ and $\cos(a)=\cos (\alpha ) \cosh (\beta )-i \sin (\alpha ) \sinh (\beta )$.

Comment: sorry but I don't get it. Do you have perhaps a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of Taylor expansion, $a_n = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}.$ What we are left to find is the $n$-th derivative of $\sin(z)$ evaluated at $z = a.$ Since $\sin$ is a solution to $f'' = -f,$ we have

$f^{(0)}(a) = f^{(4)}(a) = \dotsb = f^{(4k)}(a) = \sin(a);$

$f^{(5)}(a) = f^{(9)}(a) = \dotsb = f^{(4k+1)}(a) = \cos(a);$

$f^{(6)}(a) = f^{(10)}(a) = \dotsb = f^{(4k+2)}(a) = -\sin(a);$

$f^{(7)}(a) = f^{(11)}(a) = \dotsb = f^{(4k+3)}(a) = -\cos(a);$

We also have the following trig identities:

$\sin(x + \pi/2) = \cos(x);$

$\sin(x + \pi) = -\sin(x);$

$\sin(x + 3\pi/2) = -\cos(x);$

$\sin(x + 2\pi) = \sin(x).$

We deduce then that $a_n = \dfrac{\sin(a + \frac{[n \mod 4]\pi}{2})}{n!}.$